# Better approach to summarizing data with multiple groupings and querying resulting summary data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, bigdata, database

I'm looking to improve the design of our reporting system is currently as follows:

Raw data (in SQL Server) is summarized daily into summary tables via straightforward enough SQL.

What we have in the summary table then is something like the following (normalized but example below just for demonstrative purposes):

(group bys):

- Day
- Country
- Campaign
- Product
- Device Vendor
- Device Model
- Browser
- Operating System
- Channel

  (sum/counts):
- Clicks
- Signups
- Cost
- Revenue

We have a custom reporting tool that allows the user to query the above summary data with every possible combination of groupings and filters.
e.g select Day, Device Vendor, Sum(Clicks) from table where Country='Spain' and Campaign='Campaign1'

It's powerful because we can look at the data in every conceivable way but the drawback is that the more detail (i.e the greater the number of selection columns) in the table the more data there is and this inevitably impacts speed.

What are the general approaches taken to this? Should I be looking at Big Data solutions (Hadoop etc) or can it be easily achieved in relational databases? I'm sure this is a common challenge but until now we've more than adequately survived on our custom built solution, but we're needing to handle more and more data and want more detailed insights.

Comment: I believe you are asking about [Data Warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) concepts.

Comment: Yes, I agree Data Warehousing addresses the challenges we're facing but what if the data we're recording is very high in volume, 10m+ transactions per hour? I'm looking at sharding options but still, I'm concerned that whatever db solution I come up with may still fall short when there are huge spikes in traffic.